# Can str_replace('<') safeguard us from user injected code?

Tags: php, javascript, security, xss

Ok so I have some user input and i do a `echo str_replace('<', '&lt;', str_replace('&','&amp;',$_POST['input']));`

I'm wondering, is there *anyway* the user could break this filter?

Initially I'd thought this script is pretty bullet-proof, but I began to suspect its robustness after reading some article on php, character sets, and security.

Comment: What's wrong with using `htmlentities`? Am I missing something?

Comment: When you are measuring security in cumbersomeness, OPs code does have a certain appeal. The suspicion about character sets is right however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In some multibyte character sets (UTF-7 being the most notable) there are other characters that can be used as angle brackets in html.

In addition, that won't protect html attributes, since they can inject javascript by using a quotation. So, where you'd doing:

```
<input value="<?= $replaced_value ?>" />
```

they can pass the value

```
" onclick="alert(5)" x="
```

which will result in

```
<input value="" onclick="alert(5)" x="" />
```

There are many different ways that someone can exploit your code if you don't use the right methods. Using OWASP's encoding library [Reform](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Encoding_Project) you can encode everything you need to.

The bottom line is that you shouldn't ever, under any circumstances, roll your own security code unless you absolutely have to. 3rd party libraries where multiple security experts have spent a large amount of time on the problem is the best thing you can do, both from an efficiency standpoint and a liability standpoint.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the first paragraph, do you mean that `htmlspecialchars()` will break if someone manage to insert in a "fake" angle-bracket which php failed to notice but the browser recognise?

Comment: http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html#XSS_UTF-7 - it's the reason that I now use Reform and its whitelist instead of using blacklist functions like htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 6):

It depends on where that input ends up.

For instance, if at some point you wind up with a template that is (poorly) constructed like this...

```
<a href="<?php echo $somevar; ?>">a link</a>
```

Then someone could inject code by simply using the following input:

```
javascript:do_whatever()
```

Even if the output isn't normally echoed into the `href` field, something like this...

```
<a title="<?php echo $somevar; ?>" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

could still be vulnerable if the input is...

```
" href="javascript:do_whatever()
```

So basically... filters have to be sensitive to the contexts in which they are being used. A commonly used function is [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) which handles a lot of the common cases.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a quick look at the [`htmlspecialchars()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

> The translations performed are:
>
> ```
> '&' (ampersand) becomes '&amp;'
> '"' (double quote) becomes '&quot;' when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
> "'" (single quote) becomes '&#039;' only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
> '<' (less than) becomes '&lt;'
> '>' (greater than) becomes '&gt;'
> ```

So the big one is that `>` isn't valid in HTML unless it's part of a tag, but presumably browsers will ignore this.

The quote escaping is needed if you're putting this inside some quotes, like:

```
echo "<input name='x' value='" . htmlspecialchars($input) . "'/>";
```

That said, why not just use `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: Cool, didn't notice that function. Btw why do we need to swap `>` to `&glt;` ?

Comment: @Pacerier - `>` in HTML (and XML) ends an element, so it's technically not valid inside character data (normal page content). Realistically, most browsers won't care, but I think your page won't validate, and might parse slower (or even in quirks mode if you're really unlucky).